# Azure webapp not reading appsettings.json file

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

*FINAL EDIT:
I have made some discoveries that changes the original question. Trying to figure out which appsettings file is used i went into the online App Service Editor and changed the clientId to a string reflecting the file they where in. I changed all the appsettings. Still the same error message saying that a specific clientID did not match the replyUrl. 
Thing is, none of the appsetting files contained this cliendId anymore. So i started deleting appsetting file after file. I restarted app after every delete. Still the same error message. Even when there where no appsettings at all still the same error mesage with the same ClientId. 
So im thinking that Azure maybe was stuck with some old code version and didnt build anything new uploaded. That would explain this behaviour. Ive made  a new app and now the clientId in the error message shows the clientId in the appsettings file as expected. 
Now my question is, is there maybe some super restart function since the site seemed to be stuck? Id like to know if it happens again.*

**Original post:**

I have a .net core 2 application using AzureAD authentication. It works on my local machine using the AzureAD for authentication. But when accessing the online site I get this error:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: '267b122b-b3e7-4ac0-a235-fc3019fc1e49'.

I have checked the url in AppRegistration/ReplyURLs and its 
  https://siteadress.azurewebsites.net

I have also checked so that the applicationId is correct in the `appSettings.json`.

I actually have four versions of the same code. 
  Local and Azure sites in my companies Azure account. 
  Local and Azure sites in my own test Azure account.

They all work except the azure version on my companies account.

This error message saying that reply url doesn't match shows upp whatever I put in the `appsettings.json`. I have tried deploying wrong information in the applicationId, tennantId and domain. I have tried many times and restarted the site every time. Still, I get this error message. So I've come to the conclusion that `appsettings.json` is not being read by the site.

I have checked in appsettings in azure portal and it only has the DEFAULT_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 6.9.2.

The appsettings.json file is correct.

When I change the applicationID in the `appsettings.development.json` to "HelloWorld" and run the site locally, I get the error stating that there is no matching reply URL configured for the application "HelloWorld". That way I can see it's being read. But not in the azure site.

Here is what is in the Azure section of the `appSettings.json`:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "GraphInstance": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "GraphVersion": "v1.0",
    "Domain": "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxx-862d-4076-8aaf-e504b2cdd263",
    "ClientId": "267b122b-b3e7-4ac0-a235-fc3019fc1e49!",
    "ClientSecret": "*******************************",
    "Scopes": "openid email profile offline_access",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "BaseUrl": "https://siteadress.azurewebsites.net"
  }
```

launchSettings.json

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:1940/",
      "sslPort": 44371
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:1940/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "HiQ_Adress": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:1941/"
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public const string ObjectIdentifierType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier";
    public const string TenantIdType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid";

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
        .AddCookie();

        services.Configure<AzureAdOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

        services.AddSingleton<IMyProfileAppService, MyProfileAppService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAddressAppService, AddressAppService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationHelper, AuthenticationHelper>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAzureAdUserService, AzureAdUserService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IGraphApiClient, GraphApiClient>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //     template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure on production it is not searching for appsettings.production.json, this depends on the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT setting.

Comment: Im not sure. But i do have the same code working in my private Azure account. However, i looked in the launchsettings.json. Ill paste into the original post.

Comment: show how you setup configuration sources in your app using `IConfigurationBuilder`

Comment: also in some places you wrote `appSettings.json` and in some places `appsettings.json`. Keep in mind that the filename is case-sensitive for `.AddJsonFile` method.

Comment: @Set the builder is as per default When using the Microsoft template. Ill show it in a moment. About the spelling. I will check it in the code but it should be the same.

Comment: @Set Ive updated the original post with the startup.cs. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ive updated the op with some new discoveries.

Comment: @Lautaro, did you find out the cause?

Comment: @AnupKattel No. Its still not clear why it went down like it did. But i dont have that problem anymore after deleting and redoing averything.